# Can this tile seam be repaired?

Tags: water, shower, tile, grout, damage

We have lived in this house for 7 years and are just now noticing that the grout has worn through in two spots on the shower floor. The rest of the grout lines seem intact to me and I do not see any evidence of loose tiles. How likely it is that water damage has occurred? Is further investigation required? What remediation do you recommend? We plan to live here for another 10 years or so and do not anticipate any major remodeling.  Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpAAe.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can be tough with thin grout lines, but cleaning it out along with a quick acid etch wash rinse and put fresh grout in and seal.

Answer (score 3):

Saw it out and re-grout. It's what grout saws are made to do.

For best results, saw out all the grout on the parts you are fixing and replace it all - it's difficult to match new to old (even if you can find "the same color" it won't be the same after 10 years in use, so new and old won't match), and also if two spots failed, the rest may not be far behind. Better to replace it all at once.

No particular reason to expect water damage from this symptom - the waterproofing membrane is below the tile, grout, and thinset the tile is in. The grout gets wet and should not have an issue with getting wet.

This is neither a sign that the waterproofing membrane is damaged nor a sign it's OK - it's unrelated.